# qiskit.QuantumCircuit and qiskit.QuantumCircuit.draw()

Tags: qiskit, programming

The first time I create a two qubits, two bits circuit and draw it the output is:

```
q0_0 
q0_1 
c0_0 
c0_1
```

Each subsequent time I run my script (even after clearing all the variables) I get the following:

```
q1_0
q1_1 
c1_0 
c1_1 
. 
. 
. 
qn_0 
qn_1 
cn_0 
cn_1
```

The number next to the qubit or classical bit increases every time. Is this a bug, is there a way to avoid this?

I am using Qiskit 0.19.6.

[image: 12th time executing my script]

[image: 13th time executing my script]

Answer (score 5):

It's not a bug, if you don't give concrete names to the registers then Qiskit will number them increasingly. If you want them to have the same name, you can do that like

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister

qr = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
cr = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
circuit.draw()
```